# Universal Windows app crashes without an exception?

Tags: debugging, crash, in-app-purchase, win-universal-app

I have an app that currently crashes sometimes when attempting to do an in-app-purchase on Windows Phone 10. It seems to crash without throwing an exception. I am thinking maybe another thread is crashing the app? However it does not appear that the App's `UnhandledException` event is dispatching.

- This crashes about 5 seconds into running `RequestProductPurchaseAsync(sku)`.
- It does not crash if the debugger is attached. (This confuses me.)
- The log before `RequestProductPurchaseAsync(sku)` is displayed and written to disk.
- I never see the log in `OnUnhandledException`.

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        try {
            if (IsSimulation) {
                purchaseResult = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(sku);
            }
            else {
                Debug.Log("PurchaseProductAsync is attempting REAL PURCHASE NOW!");
                // Crash ~5 seconds into this call. No exception is thrown.
                purchaseResult = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(sku);
                //  This does not display.
                Debug.Log("PurchaseProductAsync got result " + (purchaseResult == null ? "null" : purchaseResult.Status.ToString()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception purchaseExc) {
            purchaseResult = null;
            result.ErrorCode = "-285";
            result.ErrorException = purchaseExc;
            result.ErrorMessage = "Exceptional Error";
            Debug.Log("PurchaseProductAsync got an exception when attempting to purchase from CurrentApp or CurrentAppSimulator. " + purchaseExc.GetType() + ": " + purchaseExc.Message);
        }
    });
```

Any ideas on how I can capture or debug this crash?

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    appCallbacks = new AppCallbacks();
    UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
}

private void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Never seems to run
    Debug.Log("Received unhandled exception");
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run the debugger in mixed mode? (i.e. not just Managed)

Comment: Where would that setting be in Visual Studio 2015?
Answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbaht4dh.aspx 1) Go to the project's properties. Debug section. Change Application process to Mixed (Managed and Native)

Comment: I recieve error "Unable to start debugging 'U:\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\<PackageId>\<Product>.exe' The debugger does not support debugging managed and native code at the same time  on the platform of the target computer/device. Configure the debugger to debug only native code or only managed code."

Comment: I attempted to debug using only native debugging. The app does not crash with the debugger attached. There are exceptions being thrown, but when I try to inspect it I'm told that I'm missing .pdb symbol files for a lot of Microsoft dlls. I can find the x86 and x64 ones on my desktop, but I seem to be missing the arm ones.